# FileSystemWatcher and trigger Form method from OnChange method

Tags: c#, winforms, filesystemwatcher

I maintaining Windows Forms application which helping to prepare some files. One of those files is much easier to edit in Notepad++, that why users wanted possibility to edit that in mentioned program. I wanted to have logic which will reload data from that particular file once it will be edited in external program. I found in Internet that `FileSystemWatcher` might be useful for me, that's why I created button which define `FileSystemWatcher` and start looking for changes:

```
private void btnNotepadPP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ......
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(OtherFileName);
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
    watcher.Filter = "FILE.xml";

    watcher.Changed += OnChanged;

    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    ......
}
```

And here I have defined `OnChanged`:

```
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Edited!");

    //What I wanted to do
    ReloadFormSilently(); // -> Main Form method
}
```

And that is my problem, `ReloadFormSilently()` is not visible from `OnChanged`. That might be very obvious, but I couldn't find way how to resolve it. I know that I'm missing some reference to Main Form, but I don't know how to pass this reference. I thought even about overloading `OnChanged` but really fast I realized that I don't know how to do that. I will be grateful for some advice how to resolve that. Or maybe there is simpler way?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Remove `static` from `OnChanged`

Comment: @Zer0 Yes, you are right of course. That worked as I intended. Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to **@Zer0** - Solution was simple:

```
private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Edited!");

    //What I wanted to do
    ReloadFormSilently(); // -> Main Form method
}
```

`static` makes the problem. Cheers!